# Cython vs. Python implementation of Pandas groupBy()

Tags: python, performance, pandas, cython

I have some code that performs some calculations on different slices of data and then places the results into a multi-indexed pandas dataframe. Then each of these dataframes, containing the results for a data slice, are concatenated together with `pandas.concatenate()`. Finally, I use `pandas.groupBy()` to collapse this big dataframe and do sums.

Recently I made some changes to the code generating the results that are put into each of the dataframes that then get concatenated. As a result of those changes the `groupBy()` function runs a lot slower. By looking at some basic profiling, it seems `groupBy()` is using the pure Python implementation as opposed to the Cython one.

Unfortunately I cannot paste code snippets nor data. However, could someone point me towards what to check in order to find out what is causing the issue? For instance, data types in the dataframe are all homogeneous and pre-determinable?

Thank you.

Comment: Even if you can't post your actual code, you can attempt to make a representative example (what types of data, what groupby ops, etc).   You're unlikely to get any help without that.